# Asynchronous Initialization of Akka Actors

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka

I'm trying to find the proper pattern for initializing an actor asynchronously, so that I can look up dependent `ActorRef`s it needs. I want to avoid using `ActorSelection`, since it's

- ambiguous as to the number of actors it points to, and
- has some overhead that's undesirable for many `tell`s

Looking at the [Actor LifeCycle](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#actor-lifecycle) it seems to be all pretty much synchronous until the message loop starts, including `preStart`, etc., which leads me to think that I have only one of two choices:

**Use a factory method with a signature of `Future[ActorRef]`**

All dependencies for constructing the actor are resolved asynchronously and passed in via `Props`.

The main problem with this approach is that you cannot use this factory to construct an actor inside of another actor, since it then has the same problem, i.e. it's turtles all the way down, wiring up the hierarchy of all actors and their dependencies asynchronously.

**Use `become` and `stash` to transition the actor**

The actor is created with `actorOf`, immediately resulting in an `ActorRef` but it starts in an *Initialization* state, does it's dependency resolution, `stash`ing incoming messages in the meantime, and finally `become`ing the *Running* state and `unstashAll`ing.

This feels a lot more idiomatic for actors, even though my dependencies will all be `var` instead of `val`.

Both seem like a lot of overhead, making me wondering if I these are the best options or if I just haven't found the proper pattern in the docs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no reason your dependencies have to be `vars` when using become:

```
val initializing: Actor.Receive = {
  case Dependencies(d1, d2) => context.become(working(d1, d2))
}

def working(d1: Dependency, d2: Dependency): Actor.Receive = {
  case msg => d1.fetch(...) // whatever
}

def receive = initializing
```

Also, `actorFor` is a) deprecated and b) doesn't create an actor.

Comment: Edited my usage of `actorFor`, it was a typo. `become` is certainly looking like the best approach. Still can't believe there is no async version of `Props` recipes

Comment: I've created a trait for a `become`/`stash` based initialization phase with your suggestion for immutable running state: https://gist.github.com/sdether/15bc96e27ed965bd89c3